# shrinking an open domain with a smooth boundary - what is the new boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $D$ is an open, convex and bounded set in $R^3$ with a smooth boundary. I want to shrink $D$ a bit but preserve the same 'shape'. What I'd like to do is to take inward normals at each point of the boundary, move by $\epsilon$ on each of them and then consider the region bounded by this new 'boundary'. There is a theorem (I think it's called mattress theorem) which says that if the boundary is smooth and $\epsilon$ is small enough then the little normal intervals of length $\epsilon$ are pairwise disjoint. My question is - does this new set (boundary translated by $\epsilon$) form in fact a boundary of some open and convex subset of $D$? It seems intuitive that it should, but I have no idea on how to show that - a reference or at least a confirmation would be most appreciated. Easy to see that it works for balls for example, but that's a pretty special case.

(also I wasn't sure what tags to add, I'd be grateful if someone verified that, I've put the "pde" because this question arose when considering some partial differential equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to define the shrinking process differently, and then show it's equivalent to yours. Namely, let $$\begin{split}D_\epsilon&=\{x\in D:\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial D)>\epsilon\} \\ &= \{x\in D: \exists r>\epsilon \text{  such that }    B_r(x)\subset D \} \end{split} \tag{1}$$ 
The second form shows that $D$ is convex: given $x_1,x_2\in D_\epsilon$, let $r$ be the smaller of $r_1,r_2$ and observe that for any $\lambda\in (0,1)$ the ball $B_r(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)$ is contained  in $D$. Openness is clear from either form.

If $\partial D$ is $C^2$ smooth and $\epsilon$ is small, then the translation along normal indeed produces $\partial D_\epsilon$ (this fact does not rely on convexity). Indeed, consider the line segment from $x$ to the nearest boundary point: this segment is normal to the boundary. Pushing the boundary by $\epsilon$ along the normal is the same as taking   the points at distance  $\epsilon $ from the boundary.

Comment: you're right, thank you. Do I also get that the boundary of $D_{\epsilon}$ is smooth if $D$'s was? Can I say that the transformation of pushing along respective normals is smooth as a transformation defined on the boundary of $D$?

Comment: @mm-aops Yes. A tubular neighborhood (look up the term) of $\partial D$  is diffeomorphic to the product of $\partial D$ with an interval. The boundary of shrunk set is the image of a fibre in this product under the diffeomorphism.